# Infinite descending set sequence

Tags: elementary-set-theory

In ZFC theory, the axiom of regularity guarantees there's no infinite descending sequence. But it seems I found one. Define $x_n=\{n, x_{n+1}\}$, then it is obvious that $x_0\ni x_1\ni x_2\ni\cdots$. And to see why's no contradiction with the axiom. Take any set $x_i$, there are only two elements $i$ and $x_{i+1}$. Neither of them intersects with $x_i$.

So what's wrong with this construction?

Comment: @ReneSchipperus Sure? I don't think so.

Comment: What's the $n$ for? Why don't you just "define" $x_n=\{x_{n+1}\}$?

Comment: @bof If $x_n=x_{n+1}$, then violates the axiom of regularity.

Comment: Huh? Your sequence of $x_n$'s violates the axiom of regularity. I thought that was your point, that you had found a sequence of sets violating the axiom of regularity. I'm asking why it needs to be so complicated, why not define it more simply by $x_n=\{x_{n+1}\}.$

Comment: @bof I mean, $x=\{x\}$ is obviously contradictory to the axiom of regularity. But for my construction, I can't see there's any contradiction.

Comment: And your sequence of $x_n$'s obviously contradicts the axiom of regularity, which says that for any nonempty set $S$ there is an element $x\in S$ such that $x\cap S=\emptyset.$ So let $S=\{x_0,x_1,x_2,\dots\};$ what is the element $x\in S$ such that $x\cap S=\emptyset?$

Comment: @bof Well, how do you know that, without any prior of sequence $x_i$? So my construction avoids the hypothesis.

Comment: The way I "know" there is a sequence satisfying $x_n=\{x_{n+1}\}$ is the same way you "know" there is a sequence satisfying $x_n=\{n,\{x_{n+1}\}\}.$

Comment: @bof I don't deny the existence of your construction if you can guarantee that $x_n\neq x_{n+1}$. As for $S$, the axiom of regularity denies its existence, not $x_i$'s

Comment: Why don't you just define $x=\{0,x\}$ and then you have $x\ni x\ni x\ni\dots.$ The axiom of regularity denies the existence of the set $\{x\}$ but not the existence of $x.$

Comment: @bof $x$ intersects its own element $x$, hence not allowed

Comment: The axiom of regularity says that a nonempty set can't intersect **all** of its elements. There is no law against a set intersecting **some** of its elements. For example the set $\{\emptyset,\{\emptyset\}\}$ intersects its element $\{\emptyset\}.$

Comment: @bof  Oh sorry. But $x=\{0,x\}$ is a circular definition. Anyway, why can't I just define as my way? Your proof using S, I think there's no axiom supported for an infinite set just including each element as wanted.

Comment: The problem with defining $x_n$ in terms of $x_{n+1}$ is the same as the problem with a circular definition: you are defining something in terms of something which you have not already defined.

Comment: @bof Thanks. Very clear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [Axiom of Regularity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_regularity) says that, for any nonempty set $y,$ there is an element $x\in y$ such that $x\cap y=\emptyset.$ This axiom, in the presence of the other axioms of [Zermelo-Fraenkel set theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zermelo%E2%80%93Fraenkel_set_theory) (particularly the [Axiom Schema of Replacement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_schema_of_replacement)), implies that there is no infinite descending
$\in$-sequence.

For suppose there were a sequence $\langle x_n:n\in\omega\rangle$ such that $x_{n+1}\in x_n$ for each $n.$ Then, by Replacement, the range of that sequence would exist, i.e., the set $y=\{x_n:n\in\omega\}.$ Thus $y$ is a nonempty set, and $y\cap x\ne\emptyset$ for each $x\in y,$ since $x_{n+1}\in y\cap x_n.$ But this contradicts the Axiom of Regularity.

Comment: There is a tricky point there: this argument only works because the universe in which the sequence is is the one in which we are working. More generally, it applies to transitive models, but there is nothing in ZFC to guarantee that in any given model of ZFC there are no infinite descending sequences (in fact, it is an easy exercise to show that if ZFC is consistent, it has models with infinite descending chains).

Comment: I agree, but I felt that it was a point that should be mentioned.

Answer (score 3):

In order to define $x_n$ you need to know what is $x_{n+1}$. So the only way your sequence makes sense is if there is an infinite decreasing sequence of natural numbers.

Or, let me simply ask you this, what is the first element of the sequence, exactly?

Comment: So the problem is, I don't know whether $x_1$ exists, right? Can I just define $y_1=\{1\}$, and $y_{n}$ is constructed by adding the innermost set of $y_{n-1}$ an element $\{n\}$. So $x_1$ is the limit of $y_n$.

Comment: That makes no sense to me, I'm sorry.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: You are right, but I don't think that's a complete answer. This is obviously a flaw in the construction (which, I think, could be correct if we had assumed something like Aczel's anti-regularity axiom), but that does not mean such a sequence does not exist, while axiom of regularity does imply that not only does this construction not work, but in fact, there is no such thing (for transitive models).